# HttpContext.Current.Cache performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, caching

I'm on IIS6 > ASP .NET > C# > WebService

I have to put in Cache a lot of data (thousands of serialized object of about 2MB each).
How does IIS6 manage `HttpContext.Current.Cache` - does it save in RAM or temp file? 
Can I compress data before caching?
What are the alternatives of `HttpContext.Current.Cache?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it is saved in RAM. If you have saving that large amount of data you should think about saving it in a database.

Comment: datas are already supplied by the database then I do some calcul and modification on them and I return the serialised response. Should I save this response again in database?

Comment: By the sounds of it you should scale up your hardware or scale down your cache time or the data stored.

Comment: Does all of the serialized data have to accessed at once? If not why not just save the modifications in a different table and access what is only needed.